# Tag for -する verbs?

Tags: support, tags

I was looking for a tag pertaining to verbs constructed as [noun]+する. I found none, but I may have looked in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we do not have a tag [suru-verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suru-verbs) and currently questions would simply be tagged [verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs).

My feeling is that such a tag would be useful (and I welcome your effort to breathe some life into the tagging system). However, the more specialized the tag the more work it is to ensure it ends up on the relevant questions, as users may simply tag a question about *suru*-verbs [verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs).

Comment: "the more specialized the tag the more work it is to ensure it ends up on the relevant questions": this is particularly true of tags with names that may not spontaneously come to mind (I have had difficulty myself finding some tags because I simply worded the topic differently), but I think [suru-verbs] is pretty safe in this respect.

Comment: Well, you are actually *looking* for a suitable tag. Many users will just put something. For me typing `verbs` gives suggestions of six tags. One will only find the tag without typing `suru` if there are at least 30 questions tagged with it (at which point it will replace [compound-verbs] as the last item in the list of suggested tags).

Comment: This has more to do with SE than tags. The best way of handling this would be to add `grammar` as a tag and be prompted to choose between `verbs`, `nouns`, etc. and select again within `verbs`. But this is not something we can do at our level by just adding or rewording tags.

Comment: Right, my point was just that there is no existing mechanism to make choosing the correct specialized tag any easier. (As usual, this idea of tag hierarchy [appears to have been brought up on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/299332) and, as usual, is [status-unknown].)

Comment: I think that it is worth noting that there are tags for ichidan-verbs and godan-verbs.  It does seem like a small oversight to leave out the exception verbs (i.e. する and くる).

Comment: @ajsmart To be honest, I don't really see why one would need separate tags for ichidan and godan verbs. But if you wanted to ask about irregular conjugation, there is always [irregularities-exceptions] whose tag wiki says "Questions about any aspect of Japanese where there is a common rule which has a few exceptions, such as the irregular verbs."